# Integration Test with Arquillian doesn´t working on JBoss EAP 6 Remote on Linux

Tags: jboss, jboss-arquillian

When I try to execute integration test with arquillian and jboss eap 6 remote on linux, now return

> the:org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Could not deploy to container: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed

On windows work very fine as localhost as other machine.

This is my configuration:

file arquillian.xml

```
<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

 <container qualifier="jboss7" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
        <property name="managementPort">9999</property>
        <property name="username">deploy</property>
        <property name="password">xxxx</property>
    </configuration>

</container>
```

pom.xm:

```
    <profile>
        <id>test-int</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.2.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

standalone.xml = jboss eap 6.0

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <!--
          ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
          ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL 
          -->
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Which adapter and version are you using?

Comment: I edit my question answering you...thanks

Comment: try jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote:7.1.2.Final for EAP 6.0 and 7.1.3.Final for 6.1+. Or try Arquillian Chameleon to avoid it all https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-chameleon/ :)

Comment: I will try again changing the adapter version.

Comment: So guys...I changed adapter version but now I get error:org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Could not deploy to container: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed

Comment: This is running on your localhost? AS/EAP has a local authentication so if it's on the same machine username/password is not technically required. You've ran the add-user scripts etc with the username/password you have defined in arquillian.xml? I believe the user needs to have access to the management apis.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a management user in your remote instance, in your case:

user deploy/